# Thread safety question about one container

Tags: thread-safety, critical-section

Let's talk about theory a bit. We have one container, let's call it TMyObj that looks like this:

```
struct TMyObj{ 
                bool bUpdated;
                bool bUnderUpdate;
             }
```

Let a class named TMyClass have an array of the container above + 3 helpful functions. One for getting an object to be updated. One for adding update info to a certain object and one for getting an updated object. It's also called in this order. Here's the class

```
class TMyClass{
  TmyObj entries[];
  TMyObj GetObjToUpdate;
  {
     //Enter critical section
     for(int i=0; i<Length(entries); i++) 
       if(!entries[i].bUnderUpdate)
       { 
         entries[i].bUnderUpdate=true;
         return entries[i];
       }
     //Leave critical section
  }
  //the parameter here is always contained in the Entries array above 
  void AddUpdateInfo(TMyObj obj)
  {
    //Do something...
    //Enter critical section
    if(updateInfoOver) obj.bUpdated=true; //left bUnderUpdate as true so it doesn't bother us
    //Leave critical section
  }
  TmyObj GetUpdatedObj
  {
    //<-------- here
    for(int i=0; i<Length(entrues); i++)
      if(entries[i].bUpdated) then return entries[i];
    //<-------- and here?
  }
}
```

Now imagine 5+ threads using the first two and another one for using the last function(getUpdadtedObj) on one instance of the class above.

Question: Will it be thread-safe if there's no critical section in the last function?

Comment: Is this _not_ about .net? Your code looks like C#, and it is a relevant piece of information, because different languages/environments do not all provide the same sort of guarantees about thread synchronization and memory consistency.

Comment: nono it's native code(in Delphi), but since more people know C, I used C.

Comment: So you want an answer to one question (about the memory model in Delphi) but since you figure more people would be able to answer a completely different question (about the memory model in .net), you ask that one instead? Not exactly a recipe for enlightenment, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your sample code, it appears that it would be thread-safe for a *read*.  This is assuming `entries[]` is a fixed size.  If you are simply iterating over a fixed collection, there is no reason that the size of the collection should be modified, therefore making a thread-safe *read* ok.

The only thing I could see is that the result might be out of date.  The problem comes from a call to `GetUpdatedObj` -- `Thread A` might not see an update to `entries[0]` during the life-cycle of

```
for(int i=0; i<Length(entrues); i++)
      if(entries[i].bUpdated) then return entries[i];
```

if `Thread B` comes along and updates `entries[0]` while `i > 0` -- it all depends if that is considered acceptable or not.